# Why minor ticks disappear on pylab subplots

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

***Begin Edit***

After initial post I continued playing with my code.  In my subplots I am making four plots of the same data set, with each subplot having a different time range.  However, if I give each subplot the SAME time range then the minor ticks do not disappear.  This may be why Deditos could not reproduce my issue.

That being said, if I manually create each subplot (with each having a different x-axis range), set the minor tick locations, THEN set each subplot's xrange I do not see the minor ticks disappear until I set ax3's (i.e. the last subplot) range.

It seems the issue is in having different x-axis ranges.  Bizarre, I would think that by setting each axis' properties individually they would not all be tied together.

***End Edit***

I am creating one figure that has four sub-plots, all of which are time series. I have the xaxis major ticks spaced every four hours, and want minor ticks every hour. When I set the minor ticks for the first subplot (called ax1) the minor ticks appear, as they should. However, when I set the minor ticks in ax2 they show up in ax2, but the minor ticks in ax1 disappear. This repeats for ax3, and ax4. So, in the end I have only minor xaxis ticks in the fourth subplot. I had the same problem with the yaxis, but resolved this issue using yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5)) for each axis (see below). However, MultipleLocator does not seem to work for time series data. Does anyone know how I can keep my minor xaxis ticks?

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, MultipleLocator
minor = AutoMinorLocator()

# Start plotting
fig = figure( figsize=(22,11) )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221) # 8-August 2011
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222) # 9-August 2011
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223) # 23-August 2011
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224) # 24-August 2011

# This is repeated for ax2, ax3, and ax4, yielding a 2x2 grid of subplots. 

# Plot 8-August 2011 data
ax1.plot(tpan.index,tpan.no2,'.-',markersize=10)
ax1.errorbar(tacam.index,tacam.no2,yerr=0.15,fmt='r.',markersize=12)

# Format plots
suptitle('Pandora/ACAM NO$_2$ Comparison', fontsize=22)

# Define xtick locations/string labels
xtickloc = [dt.datetime.combine(dates[0],dt.time())+dt.timedelta(hours=h) for h in range(0,25,4)]
xticklab = [dt.datetime.strftime(h,'%H:%M') for h in xtickloc]

ax1.set_xlabel('Hour of Day (UTC, EST+5)',fontsize=14)
ax1.set_ylabel('NO$_2$ Column Density (molec*cm$^{-2}$ E16)',fontsize=14)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(xtickloc)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(linspace(0,1.5,7))
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor)
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
ax1.set_xticklabels(xticklab,fontsize=12,fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_yticklabels(linspace(0,1.5,7),fontsize=12,fontweight='bold')
ax1.axis( (dates[0],dates[0]+dt.timedelta(days=1),-0.05,1.5),fontsize=6,fontweight='bold')
ax1.tick_params(which='both',width=2,top='on')
ax1.tick_params(which='major',length=7)
ax1.tick_params(which='minor',length=4)
ax1.grid(linestyle='-',which='major',linewidth=1)
ax1.set_title('08-August 2011',fontsize=16)
ax1.legend( ('Pandora VCD','ACAM dSCD'),loc=2,ncol=2)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem from your code - all four subplots are drawn with the minor ticks. (Python 2.7, Matplotlib 1.0.1).

Comment: Interesting.  Mine still shows up with only ticks on the last subplot.  I changed my tags from matplotlib to pylab (I should say I TRIED to change the tag, but the change does not save...), since I am using pylab for the plotting, but I don't believe this should make THAT much of a difference.  Can you confirm whether you imported pylab or matplotlib?

Comment: FYI: I am using pylab 1.7.1 and have matplotlib 1.2.1

Comment: I imported pylab, as per your script.  Of course, I had to guess the types of `dates`, `tpan.index`, `tpan.no2`, etc and which statements you're repeating for each `ax` instance.  Those decisions might be relevant.

Comment: tpan is a pandas dataframe; 
tpan.index are datetime; 
tpan.no2 are doubles; 

I have updated my original post with more details.  Basically, I am creating the same plot four times, then adjusting the time range of the x-axis, everything else is the same.

Comment: @tnknepp When you try to tag a question with [tag:pylab] it will automatically be tagged with [tag:matplotlib] as `pylab` is a part of matplotlib, and therefore the tag is a synonym for the `matplotlib` tag. Also, see [Matplotlib, pylab, and pyplot: how are they related?](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pylab-and-pyplot-how-are-they-related).

Comment: Given the odd behavior here (i.e. all subplots minor ticks seem to be tied together, though they should be separate) do you think this is a bug in pylab/matplotlib?  I am hesitant to label it as such, but it seems to me that all subplot axes should be independent of other subplots, and this seems to not be the case here.

Comment: You should post a full example script that reproduces your problem and that we can run without editing.  The error's most likely in the bits of code you're _not_ showing us.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. I think what you need to do is:

```
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
```

instead of

```
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor)
```

You are passing the same object to each of your axes. This object's contents are modified when you plot on ax4 based on the range on that subplot. Hope it helps.